# c++ get negative numbers from complex

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

If I create a complex number with amplitude negativ (-1) and no phase (0), thus corresponding to a double of -1, and convert it back to amplitude and phase, the amplitude is not negative

```
complex<double> c;
c = polar(-1.0, 0.0);
cout << c << ", " << abs(c) << ", " << arg(c) << endl;
```

the output is

```
(-1, 0), 1, -3.14159
```

it should have been

```
(-1, 0), -1, 0
```

How can I get back the correct amplitude value?

Comment: polar(-1.0,0.0) => -180 degrees argument, 1 radius. Radius cannot be negative.

Comment: are you aware that the mapping (rho,theta)-(abs,arg) is not strictly bijective?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you explain how a debugger would help in this case

Comment: @M.M Can you explain how to even debug that incomplete code?

Comment: No. So I don't think a debugger is the right tool to help with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view, the *magnitude* (or *modulus* or *absolute value*) of a complex number should be a positive number (or 0).

Looking at the reference page for [`std::polar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/polar) it's specified that:

> Returns a complex number with magnitude r and phase angle theta.  The
>   behavior is undefined if r is negative or NaN, or if theta is infinite
>     (since C++17)

You don't specify what compiler you are using, but it is kind enough to give you the "correct" result, a complex number with magnitude 1 and phase angle -π.
Testing the same snippet with g++ 6.1 (-std=c++14) gave me:

```
(-1,-0), 1, -3.14159
```

The only difference is the negative zero, which is consistent with the negative angle.

Also note that a function like [`std::abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs) could return a negative number only if some error occured.

Comment: Indeed I was confusing magnitude here defined with the norm with a physical amplitude which can be negative (by definition).

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing real and imaginary part with absolute and phase.

Try:

```
cout << c << ", " << real(c) << ", " << imag(c) << endl;
```

Also, absolute values can NEVER be negative [by definition of polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). You could try with that:

```
complex<double> c;
c = polar(1.0, M_PI); //don't forget to include <cmath>
cout << c << ", " << abs(c) << ", " << arg(c) << endl;
```

And that will flip the phase and make the radius on the other direction of the polar coordinates.